# limit of measurable functions is measurable using preimage

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

The task is to show that if $f_n$ is a sequence of measurable functions with respect to a sigma-algebra, $\mathcal{A}$, where $f_n: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, and $f_n$ converges pointwise to $f$ on $\Omega$, then $f$ is measurable with respect to $\mathcal{A}$.

I'm not sure if this proof would be accepted but my strategy was to use the fact that given that $\mathcal{A}$ is closed under countable unions and countable intersections we have:

$$
\forall c \in \mathbb{R}, \bigcap_{m=1}^\infty \bigcup_{n=m}^\infty f_n^{-1}((c,\infty))= \limsup_{n\to\infty} f_n^{-1}((c,\infty)) \in A\tag{1}
$$

$$
\forall c \in \mathbb{R}, \bigcup_{m=1}^\infty \bigcap_{n=m}^\infty f_n^{-1}((c,\infty))=\liminf_{n\to\infty} f_n^{-1}((c,\infty)) \in \mathcal{A}\tag{2}
$$

From this it follows that both:

$$ \limsup_{n\to\infty} f_n\tag{3}
$$

$$ \liminf_{n\to\infty} f_n\tag{4}
$$

are measurable.

Further, given that $ \lim_{n\to\infty} f_n = f $:

$$ f=\limsup_{n\to\infty} f_n = \liminf_{n\to\infty} f \tag{5}$$

This proof is much shorter than what I've found on the internet so I wonder whether there might be an important gap I have failed to consider.

Comment: You could shorten the proof even further by cutting out $\limsup$ and using only $\liminf.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\bigcap\limits^{\infty}_{m=1}\bigcup\limits^{\infty}_{n=m}f_n^{-1}((c,\infty)):=\limsup\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}f_n^{-1}((c,\infty))=\inf\limits_{m\in\mathbb{N}}\sup\limits_{n\geq m}f_n^{-1}((c,\infty))$, and the $\liminf f_n$ is dually defined. The  $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} f_n$ exists iff $\limsup\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}f_n=\liminf\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}f_n$ and in which case $\limsup\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}f_n=\liminf\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}f_n=\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}f_n$.  Can you show this?  So what you have done is to have shown $\limsup\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}f_n$ to be measurable, you can similarly show the $\liminf\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}f_n$ is measurable. Therefore the set on which $\{\omega\in\Omega:\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}f_n \space\space\text{exists}\}=\{\omega\in\Omega:\limsup\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}f_n=\liminf\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}f_n\}\in\mathcal{A}$, as the $\limsup\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}f_n$ and $\liminf\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}f_n$ are measurable, and in your case the set on which the limit exists is given to be the whole of $\Omega$.
So setting $E= \{\omega\in\Omega:\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}f_n \space\space\text{exists}\}$  $(=\Omega$ in this case), and as $\limsup\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}f_n=\liminf\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}f_n=\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}f_n$ we see that $\{\omega\in E: \lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}f_n>c\}=\{\omega\in E:\liminf\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}f_n>c\}=E\cap \{\liminf\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}f_n>c\}\in\mathcal{A}$

Comment: This was submitted before you made you edited your post and did not mention "limsup" etc so with your corrected typos etc yes your argument now is correct and is what I posted as an answer